# Jenkins pipelines is multiple parametrized cron build possible?

Tags: jenkins, triggers, cron, jenkins-pipeline

I have a working Jenkins scripted pipeline, very simple.
I am also using triggers to enable pipeline to run on a schedule.

Something like this:

```
node{
    do_something()
    triggers{
        cron(‘* * * * *’)
    }
}
```

`do_something()` does various things, and takes into account some input params (and env variables)

I want to trigger pipeline multiple times - lets say once a minute with some parameters, and every hour with other parameters.
(Imagine that I would like the same pipeline to be reused for continuous and full builds)

Is it possible?
I did not found a way how to do this, I am not even sure that it can be triggered by more than one trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trigger will trigger the entire job. It doesn't trigger parts of a job, or trigger with different parameters. What you probably want to do is setup a trigger job. Just have a simple pipeline job that triggers every minute, 10 minutes, whatever you need. That job will use logic in groovy to decide what needs to be done at that time and then trigger another job or jobs with the parameters you need.

Comment: Do I understand correctly - your proposal is to trigger the job every minute (or any other lower bound granularity), and internally perform all the logic that cron should perform?

Comment: Not exactly. Thank 2 (or more) jobs. Use one job with cron to trigger the other job(s). Of course, if you have some things that should run that often, or you are running that complex of a thing, then it could get a little ugly and be about like that. You can add multiple cron entries, as well, if that makes it easier. But ultimately, it will just retrigger the entire job, so if you want to do different things at different times, you need to trigger different jobs.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having multiple "trigger jobs", too. In your case, that sounds like it might make more sense. Use the cron trigger in a job hourly, then kick off your other job with the appropriate "hourly" parameters. A different job can have a cron that fires it every 10 minutes which in turns triggers the other job with different parameters.

Comment: I see your point, I was trying to avoid having multiple jobs for a reason, we have 200+ jobs already, and its getting crowded... :)

Comment: Using Jenkins, I don't really see another way. You can't trigger pieces of a job with an individual cron trigger. Folders and views are good to manage the mess.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the [Parametrized Scheduler](https://github.com/jenkinsci/parameterized-scheduler-plugin/blob/master/README.md) as trigger. This should do the trick for you:

```
triggers {
    parameterizedCron('''
        * * * * * %PARAM1=x;PARAM2=y
        0 * * * * %PARAM3=z
    ''')
}
```